# How to proper scale around the center of a object while using mirror modifier

Tags: mirror, tools

Often I have something that looks like this:

[image]

In the image above I have the mirror modifier applied to a 12 vertices circle (or a 7 vertices half circle with the mirror modifier applied). Imagining that I have to extrude and scale around the center of the whole object (including both halves), I tend to use the cursor as the pivot, and since it's in the world origin, if often solves the problem, specially when scaling around two axis.

[image]

However, things starts to get tricky once the selection isn't aligned with the world origin. In the following image I have a semi circle inside the other, and it's not aligned to the world origin.

[image]

What I've been doing for now is creating a new vertex in the middle of the object, often by extruding a new edge to the center of the selection, and moving the pivot to the center of the newly created vertex. That way I can scale around the middle point of the object, mirrored modified included. Since blender doesn't recognize the mirrored part of the object, I can't select the middle circle and align the pivot to the center of the selection.

[image]

But by now it's starting to feel more like a hack than how to properly handle that problem, I'm feeling that I might be missing something. Is there a better way to handle this, maybe making blender recognizing both halves? Or should I just use the symmetry tools? Most people seem to use the mirror modifier so it probably is a better option to the symmetry tool (and I've noticed that those tools applies only to translating, and not extruding, cutting etc.)

Comment: it's better to work with the Mirror modifier but if you've applied it and now you have a symmetrical object, and if you make a change on a side that you want to mirror, the best is to use the Symmetrize tool, this way you don't have to remove half of your object, give it a Mirror modifier and apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extruding a vertex and set the 3D cursor to it, you can select two opposite vertices and hit ***shift*** + ***S*** -> ***cursor to selected***
so the 3D cursor will be in the center of the circle (mirror modifier included)[image]

[image]

[image]